# Uncaught Error: Object of class CompanyName could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I have two classes in PHP.

1. RequestorId.php

```
<?php

class RequestorId
{

    /**
     * @var CompanyName $CompanyName
     * @access public
     */
    public $CompanyName = null;

    /**
     * @var string $ID
     * @access public
     */
    public $ID = null;

    /**
     * @var string $ID_Context
     * @access public
     */
    public $ID_Context = null;

    /**
     * @param CompanyName $CompanyName
     * @param string $ID
     * @param string $ID_Context
     * @access public 
     * **/
    public function __construct($CompanyName, $ID, $ID_Context)
    {
      $this->$CompanyName = $CompanyName;
      $this->$ID = $ID;
      $this->$ID_Context = $ID_Context;
    }

}
```

2. CompanyName.php

```
<?php

class CompanyName
{

    /**
     * @var string $Code
     * @access public
     */
    public $Code = null;

    /**
     * @param string $Code
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct($Code)
    {
      $this->Code = $Code;
    }

}
```

I received this error **"Uncaught Error: Object of class CompanyName could not be converted to string"**, when I use them like this:

```
    $companyname = new CompanyName('SampleName');
    $requestorid = new RequestorId($companyname, '10', 'sss'); <<-- error happen here
```

Can anyone help me and point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: What is the output of  `$companyname`?

Comment: @MamaWin CompanyName Object
(
    [Code] => SampleName
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo in your `RequestorId` constructor class. Rewrite it like this:

```
public function __construct($CompanyName, $ID, $ID_Context)
    {
      $this->CompanyName = $CompanyName;
      $this->ID = $ID;
      $this->ID_Context = $ID_Context;
    }
```

You must remove `$` sign from the beginning of properties when accessing them.

When you use `$` in front of `CompanyName` it means that you want to have a dynamic property name based on what is the value of `$CompanyName` provided in constructor. Then php tries to convert your class to string but it can't and you get the error.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much for pointing that out for me @Mohammad Mirsafaei

Comment: Yw, and not forget to mark it as correct answer